# Why does the processing time hardly decrease rather than being inversely proportional to the number of processes with multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I was testing multiprocessing with the following code which calculate the inverse of a matrix of size 100 by 100.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import multiprocessing

inputs = list(range(1000))

def invmat(I):
    np.random.seed(i)
    matrix1 = np.random.rand(100, 100)
    np.linalg.inv(matrix1)
    return 0

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = num_processes)
outputs = pool.map(invmat, inputs)

t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print(f"{(t2 - t1).seconds} seconds")
```

I varied `num_processes` as 1, 2, 4, 8, 20, 40, and no argument with the command (`pool = multiprocessing.Pool()`).

I expected the time should be inversely proportional, but the result is quite weird.

The elapsed time was 0, 101, 111, 103, 88, 78, and 78 seconds, respectively.

Why does it not work at all when the number of processes is one, and why are the elapsed times virtually the same when the number of processes is 2, 4, and 8?

The OS is RHEL 7.9, the number of CPU cores is 40, the memory size is about 50GB, and the Python version is 3.9.6.
When I run the command `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`, it returns the value of 40 as expected.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes. The time with 8 processes should be much smaller than that with 4 processes, and the time with 4 processes should be smaller than that with 2 processes. However, they are virtually the same. (101, 111, 103 seconds, respectively)

Comment: Multiprocessing is expensive (shipping data between processes takes time), and when you're running numpy code that can parallelize on its own and doesn't hold the GIL in the first place, you don't buy anything for the expense, so you're just creating overhead for no reason.

Comment: numpy uses a multi-threaded OpenBLAS library, which can wreck havoc with itself in some situations, multiprocessing is one.  Try setting OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS to 1 (i.e., `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 python my_script_name.py`) to prevent the race condition.